# Выпадающий список улиц Москвы в input

Tags: yandex-maps-api, webforms

Есть ли возможность использовать API яндекса, для выбора улицы в выпадающем списке в форме заказа? В яндексе нашел только API карт.
Пример:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Конечно есть.

- [Условия](https://yandex.ru/legal/maps_api/) использования
- [Документация](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/control.ListBox-docpage/)

Если Вас по какой-то прицине не устраивает, есть еще [ФИАС](http://fias.nalog.ru/Public/NewsPage.aspx)

[структура БД](http://fias.nalog.ru/Public/Docs/%D0%A1%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%20%D0%BE%20%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B5%20%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8%20%D0%A4%D0%98%D0%90%D0%A1.doc)